# Why should we use "NSMutableArray" or "NSMutableDictionary" in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

1. `var myArray : NSMutableArray = ["First", "Second","Third"]`
2. `var myArray = ["First", "Second","Third"]`

When should we use the above given type of Array declaration in Swift.

Comment: I don't have time to write up a full answer at the moment, but there _is_ a reason to use `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` in Swift: reference semantics. If you need multiple objects to refer to the same exact instance of array (especially a mutable array), then `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` do what Swift's `Array` does not. This can be a rare need, but is a completely valid reason to use them over `Array`.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to use `NSMutableArray` when writing Swift code. Swift arrays are automatically bridged to the Objective-C `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` types:

```
let fib = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]  // immutable array bridged to `NSArray`
var friends = ["Pascal", "Jodie", "Craig"]  // mutable array bridged to `NSMutableArray`
```

The bridging is done when you use Cocoa APIs that are written in Objective-C. And vice-versa, if you get an `NSMutableArray` as a result of calling such an API, you can assign it to a Swift `Array` as long as it's a `var`.

As an example of how bridging works, let's suppose UIKit's `UITabViewController` is still natively an Objective-C API (I don't know if it's the case or not). Then in Objective-C, you can get its `@property viewControllers` which is an `NSArray`:

```
NSArray<__kindof UIViewController *> *rootViewControllers;
rootViewControllers = [myTabViewController viewControllers];
```

But in Swift you can just assign this property to a regular array (I'm explicitly giving it a type but that's not actually needed with type inference):

```
let rootViewControllers: [UIViewController]? 
rootViewControllers = myTabViewController.viewControllers
```

Conversely, you can just pass a Swift Array of `UIViewControllers` to the `setViewControllers` method (which in Objective-C is expecting an `NSArray`):

```
func buildInitialViewControllers() -> [UIViewController] { ... }

let rootViewControllers = self.buildInitialViewControllers()
myTabViewController.setViewControllers(rootViewControllers, animated=True)
```

Comment: @dirkgroten What if I want to pass my array as reference type ? In that case we should be using "NSMutableArray" right ?

Comment: No, if you're writing pure Swift, no need to use Objective-C classes. To pass any `struct` as reference instead of value, you should use `inout` in your function declaration and pass your variables using the `&` notation. But I would be really careful with that, it's rarely needed.

Comment: @dirkgroten BTW, your code example isn't showing bridging; all of the types there are pure Swift types (`fib` is `[Int]` and `friends` is `[String]`). You can illustrate this better by writing functions that return `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` and assign them to `Array` vars, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in swift we use constant `let c  =`  And  variable `var v: [String]` 
But When you get in `NSSortDescriptor` & perform sorting in that case you have to use `NSArray` & `NSMutableArray` 
which implements function

`open func sortedArray(using sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]) -> [Any] // returns a new array by sorting the objects of the receiver`

`open func sort(using sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]) // sorts the array itself`